# NGRX selector projector function returning undefined in jasmine unit test, angular 10

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, jasmine, ngrx

I am trying to project state and props into the selector. When console logging inside the selector running the test, the variables exist and work as expected. But my expect line throws errors saying expected undefined to equal ...

```js
    fit('should return the data based on ID passed in', () => {
        const props = {
            id: '67891'
        }
        const state = {
            data: [
                { id: '12345', startDate: '2018-01-01', endDate: '2019-01-01' },
                { id: '67891', startDate: '2018-01-01', endDate: '2019-01-01' },
                { id: '14567', startDate: '2018-01-01', endDate: '2019-01-01' }
            ]
        };
        const result = state.data[1]

        expect(selectors.getDataByID.projector(state, props)).toEqual(jasmine.objectContaining(result));
    });
```

```js
export const getDataByID = createSelector(
    getState,
    (state, props) => {
        const data = Object.values(state.data);
        data.find((element: any) => props.id === element.id)
    }
  );
```

I'm not sure what's going on, as reading through the docs on the NGRX site seems to support what I am doing here, so does previous examples across the web. The variable data is available in the selector, but in the test it says undefined?

Any help appreciated, fairly new to NGRX. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try returning something, the rest seems fine.

```
return data.find((element: any) => props.id === element.id)
```

Comment: This worked, but I am confused as to why. The arrow function handles the return statement for you if a match as been found, it's just shorthand syntax right? I don't understand why a second return was required, could you elaborate please?

Comment: An arrow function always returns, a "normal" function does not and you have to explicit return something. see the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Oh I see what you are saying now. Using the arrow function inside the find operator, it returned the value, but the function itself didn't return anything. I didn't make that connection. I assumed the function would natively return due to the return of the find.

Comment: Not sure if you would be able to lend a hand on this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63218420/ngrx-effect-dispatch-new-action-on-subscription-data-is-undefined ?